# jQuery/JS Keycodes: Several keycodes in one IF statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, keycode

I'm trying to set up some keycodes for an app I'm working on but it really drives me crazy.

I'm trying to set up keycodes which would say, from keyCode 65 to 91 , 44 , 47 and few others, do function.

So I have this:

```
var e = event || evt;
if ((e.keyCode > 65 || e.Keycode < 91)){
    // Do function
}
```

which works find. Now if I try to add another keycode it doesn't work.
This is what I tried:

```
if ((e.keyCode > 65 || e.Keycode < 91) && (e.keyCode == 44) && (e.keyCode == 47)){
```

Does someone help me to add different keycodes in one If statement?

Thanks alot

Comment: Are you sure it's not syntax related?  You seem to be using `e.Keycode < 91` and `e.keyCode > 65`?

Comment: Read the expression out loud to yourself to see if it makes sense.  "If the code is between 65 and 91, and it's equal to 44, and it's equal to 47, then do the following: ..."  Basically, you should replace those `&&` operators with `||`.

Comment: (e.keyCode > 65 || e.Keycode < 91) is valid for all possible keycode values. You should review your boolean logic.

Comment: @Pointy I read it as: If code is between 65 and 91, and code is 44, and code is 47 do function?

Comment: @Pointy thanks alot. What do I use for EXCEPT. So like I might don't want to use from 65 to 91 except 70. ?

Comment: Oh also what @Andri said - that first sub-expression is goofed.  Every possible keycode is "greater than 65 or less than 91".  Read `||` as **or** and `&&` as **and** and you'll figure it out.  Also, to get the effect of **except**, you just use **and** (`&&`).

Comment: Also also, you probably want ">= 65" if you want to include upper-case "A".

Comment: I think this is one of the extremely rare cases on SO where including code in a question confused the hell out of everyone

Comment: @Pointy Instead of asking a new question. Can you type me a quick except method? I tried this: if ( (e.keyCode >= 31 || e.Keycode <= 90) && (e.keyCode >= 48 || e.Keycode <= 57)) which should include from 31 to 90 except from 48 to 57 but doesn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```js
if (
  // get all the keys between 65-90
  (e.keyCode >= 65 && e.keyCode <= 90) 
  // or  44 or 47
  || e.keyCode == 44 || e.keyCode == 47)
{
   // do stuff
}
```

If the conditional logic is tripping you up, I think you might be best served by thinking about the numbers you want to *include* (not exclude). Break them into ranges and put each range on its own line. Start with pseudo code:

```
if 
  // keys between 31-47
  // or keys between 58-90
then
  // do stuff
end
```

Then fill in the conditions:

```js
if (
  // keys between 31-47
  (e.keyCode >= 31 && e.keyCode <= 47) 

  // or keys between 58-90
  || (e.keyCode >= 58 && e.keyCode <= 90) 
)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Instead of asking a new question. Can you type me a quick except method? I tried this: if ( (e.keyCode >= 31 || e.Keycode <= 90) && (e.keyCode >= 48 || e.Keycode <= 57)) which should include from 31 to 90 except from 48 to 57 but doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: @jQuerybeast I added some more info which might be useful to you

Answer (score 0):

If you want everything from 31 to 90 except for those from 48 through 57:

```
if (e.keyCode >= 31 && e.keyCode <= 90 && !(e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57)) {
  // whatever 
}
```

Now that could be written equivalently as:

```
if (e.keyCode >= 31 && e.keyCode <= 47 || e.keyCode >= 58 && e.keyCode <= 90) {
  // whatever
}
```

Comment: have you tried this? Cause it doesn't seem to be working. Thanks alot sir

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should work, but I have no idea what the rest of your code is doing. You should be aware that **key codes** are not the same as **character codes**.  If you're expecting "keydown" and "keyup" events to give you ASCII/UTF character codes, well, they won't.

Comment: Well I was just alerting the keycode and it wasn't working. For some reason only this worked: if ((e.keyCode >= 58) || (e.keyCode <= 45) || (e.keyCode == 47)). I am calling everything greater than 58, less than 45 and 47 to call the alert. So numbers and the period are not alerting. Thanks anyway

Answer (score -1):

```
if ((e.keyCode > 65 && e.Keycode < 91) || e.keyCode == 44 || e.keyCode == 47){
   //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Not quite @Andri - that will never be true, as written, because neither 44 nor 47 are between 65 and 91.

Comment: ouch! I thought @jQuerybeast was getting tired. I see now that I must immediately stop coding for today, or risk regretting it tomorrow. Fixed it btw.